# Shortcode display outside the div

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, shortcode, actions

I have created a shortcode that retrives and displays a form.The content of the attribute in HTML.

```
function check_my_login( $atts)
    {

        return '<form action="" name="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Project Description</label>
                    <textarea name="p_description" placeholder="Project Description" class="form-control"><?php if (isset($_POST['p_description']) && $_POST['p_description'] != '') echo $_POST['p_description'] ?></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Project Attachment</label>
                    <input type="file" name="p_attachment">
                </div>
</form>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'kentaUser', 'check_my_login' );
```

Now use this shortcode inside the Post/page.

Like this

```
 <div class='manage_page'>[kentaUser]</div>
 But my shortcode content display out side the div.Display upper side in post/page content.
 <div class='manage_page'></div>
```

Any one short out this problem.

Comment: You are echoing output inside your shortcode. You should not do that. **All output** needs to be returned

Comment: any idea for manage this..

Comment: Correct this line `<textarea>.......</textarea>`, your issue is in between those tags

Comment: Any html code added here display out side of div . I think <textarea> not a issue.

Comment: The actual tags in not your issue. Your issue **is** in that line of code. You are echoing values in between your textarea tags. Please recheck your code properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

Concatenate the html then return it.

```
function check_my_login( $atts)
{

    $html = '<form action="" name="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $html .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $html .= '<label for="description">Project Description</label>';
    $html .= '<textarea name="p_description" placeholder="Project Description" class="form-control">';

    if(isset($_POST['p_description']) && $_POST['p_description'] != ''){
        $html .= $_POST['p_description'];
    }

    $html .= '</textarea>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $html .= '<label>Project Attachment</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="file" name="p_attachment">';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    return $html;
}

 add_shortcode( 'kentaUser', 'check_my_login' );
```

Comment: You don't have to do it this way, you can, as the OP did just return the html, but then it must be done properly. The advantage of your method (which I also use ) is, it is easier to read and cleaner. +1 for your approach :-)

Comment: It's working... Great.........

Answer (score 1):

If you like me come to this answer because you get this error when using **template parts** in your **shortcode**, then I like more the answer from WordPress Core Developer [Konstantin Kovshenin](https://konstantin.blog/2013/get_template_part-within-shortcodes/) to buffer the output:

In your shortcode function:

```
// start buffer
ob_start();

// call template (with html output)
get_template_part( '/path/to/template/file' );

// return buffered output
return ob_get_clean();
```