# How can I prevent a shortcode div from extending beyond its boundaries?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, shortcode

I have a shortcode for user-defined social media buttons that works well, except for the fact that the div extends beyond its boundaries, meaning that if this shortcode is called in a widget, the following widgets are also encompassed within the shortcode's div & shortcode-specific styling impacts the following widgets. I think what's happening is probably akin to [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191045/shortcode-display-outside-the-div) but I'm not sure where I've gone awry because I'm not echoing anything in this code.

If the shortcode is placed last, it works perfectly but that's not exactly good UX, is it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function smb_function( $atts ) {
    ?> <div class="social_button_shortcode"><?php
    $smb = array('fb', 'ig', 'tw', 'pi', 'li', 'et', 'fl', 'rd', 'tu', 'gr', 'yt', 'sn', 'em');
    $smb_url = array();
    foreach ( $smb as $index => $site ) {
        $thisURL = get_theme_mod ( 'themeslug_' . $site . '_url', '');
        if ( $thisURL != '' ) { 
            $smb_url[$site] = $thisURL;
            if ( $site == 'em' ) { if ( strncasecmp($smb_url[$site],"mail",4) and $smb_url[$site] != ''  ) { $smb_url[$site] = "mailto:" . $smb_url[$site]; } } 
            if ( $site != 'em' and ( strncasecmp($smb_url[$site],"http",4) and $smb_url[$site] != '' ) ) { $smb_url[$site] = "https://" . $smb_url[$site]; } 
        }
    } 
    
    $smb_img = array(   
        'fb' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-facebook-f"',
        'tw' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-twitter"',
        'rd' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-reddit-alien"',
        'em' => $smb_dir . 'class="far fa-envelope"',
        'et' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-etsy"',
        'fl' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-flickr"',
        'ig' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-instagram"',
        'li' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-linkedin-in"',
        'pi' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-pinterest-p"',
        'gr' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-goodreads-g"',
        'sn' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"',
        'tu' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-tumblr"',
        'yt' => $smb_dir . 'class="fab fa-youtube"',
    );

    if ( count($smb_url) > 0 ) {
                foreach($smb_url as $index => $site ){
        $return_string .= '<div class="smbwrap">';
        $return_string .= '<a target="_blank" href="' . $smb_url[$index] . '"><i ' . $smb_img[$index] . '></i></a>';
        $return_string .= '</div>';
        }

        return $return_string;
    } 

    ?></div>
    <?php
}

add_shortcode('socialbuttons', 'smb_function');
?>
```

Yes, I realize that adding shortcodes to a theme isn't necessarily sanctioned by the poobas but the potential for a conflict here is incredibly low.

Answer (score 0):

> because I'm not echoing anything in this code.

But you are! This code:

```php
function smb_function( $atts ) {
    ?> <div class="social_button_shortcode"><?php
```

Is the same as:

```php
function smb_function( $atts ) {
    echo ' <div class="social_button_shortcode">';
```

Likewise with the closing div tag at the end. **Any form of direct output in a shortcode will break it,** wether it was done via `echo`, `print`, `printf`, or other WP functions.

The shortcode also breaks the rule that shortcodes should return their content, because it only returns when `if ( count($smb_url) > 0 ) {` is true. But what if it isn't true? And notice that the function can never reach the closing div tag because of the `return`.

As an example, what would the output of this shortcode be:

```php
add_shortcode( 'blank', function() {} );
```

It's equivalent to this:

```php
add_shortcode( 'blank', function() { return NULL; } );
```

And this:

```php
add_shortcode( 'blank', function() { echo "Hello World!"; return NULL; } );
```

All 3 shortcodes produce a null value.

If you absolutely must output directly, use an output buffer to catch it and assign the result to a variable.

tip: typehint the shortcode function as returning a string, it'll make it more obvious if you don't return a string

Comment: ‍♂️ Thanks Tom, I've got to run an errand in a minute but you've definitely given me good feedback to work on & I appreciate it.

Comment: Tom, I changed ```return``` to ```echo``` & it's working as expected. I know it's not the neatest way to do it & I *am* planning on reworking this shortcode to do it the right way but is there a pressing reason not to use the ```echo``` method in the interim? 

Nevermind, I'm being obtuse, it doesn't work right this way in all settings.

Comment: `echo` outputs to the browser. It's not that `echo` itself is inherently bad, it's what `echo` does that's the problem, shortcodes return their content, they do not send it directly to the browser

Comment: Right - I've just made a massive batch of gluhwein so I'll probably be done soon on this but I've switched that ```return``` to ```print``` and it's working, mostly. The function finishes now & it behaves as expected in a widget however if it's placed in a TE, it appears above the rest of the content, so I've got homework!

Comment: yep if it outputs it'll appear the moment the code runs, not the place the shortcode was written. The part I mentioned in my answer isn't the only part of that function that outputs directly. The problem becomes even more apparent when you do something that requires nesting shortcodes or getting shortcode output that isn't for the frontend